# word-by-word text animation in powerpoint

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I am trying to animate text so that it appears word-by-word. I have followed the steps:

- Create text in a Textbox
- Click `Animations` ribbon
- Click `Appear`
- In the Animations formatting options, click `Text Animations`

  - In `Animate Text`, select `By word`

However, when I do this, the animation makes the first word appear, and on the next click makes all of the words appear.

Is there something else I need to change?

I am using PowerPoint v15.24 for OSX

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be anything else you need to do, although you should perhaps check the Effects Options for the delay between words. Perhaps it is too long.

For this animation you don't click to make each word appear, they appear after a time interval. When you click it will bring everything up at once because the click takes you on to the next item in the animation list, not the next word. So in other words your click says, "no matter how many words you got around to displaying, move on to the next thing."

If you want to click to make each individual word appear you'll have to make each word a separate text box and animate it individually.

Answer (score 1):

I have had luck working around the "word-by-word" approach by doing this...

1. Enter your text.
2. Create a rectangle shape (or insert a rectangle picture) that is the same color as the slide background. Arrange the shape/graphic above the text (Bring to Front).
3. Select the rectangle and choose a "fly out" or "float out" animation, then choose the right direction arrow to make the animation effect go from left to right.

The animation will reveal the underlying text. You can open the animation pane and play with timings. It's also even slicker if the rectangle is created as a graphic with a faded left edge so that, as it flies out, the text seems to fade in as it is revealed.